# How can I have a dictionary of dictionaries with Codable in Swift4

Tags: json, swift4, codable

I am currently sending an array of dictionaries to backend like the following-

```
"args": [
{
    "mobileData" =     {
        "accessState" = 1;
        "changeState" = 0;
    };
},
{
    "bluetooth" =     {
        "accessState" = 1;
        "changeState" = 0;
    };
}]
```

I use the Swift4 Codable protocols to encode/decode these and it works fine.

However, the backend expects that whole `args` as an object (dictionary) with all other KVPs (e.g. mobileData, bluetooth etc.) inside it, like the following-

```
"args":{  
      "mobileData":{  
         "accessState":1, 
         "changeState":0
      },
    "bluetooth" =     {
        "accessState" = 1;
        "changeState" = 0;
    };
}
```

Not sure how I can use Swift Codable protocols to create something like that without making the "values" inside "args" a string. Any help would be appreciated. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each dictionary is represented by a struct. Like this:

```
struct States:Encodable {
    let accessState:Int
    let changeState:Int
}
struct Args:Encodable {
    let mobileData:States
    let bluetooth:States
}
struct Wrapper:Encodable {
    let args:Args
}
let json = Wrapper(
    args: Args(
        mobileData: States(accessState: 1, changeState: 0),
        bluetooth: States(accessState: 1, changeState: 0)
    )
)
let data = JSONEncoder().encode(json)
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
// {"args":{"mobileData":{"accessState":1,"changeState":0},"bluetooth":{"accessState":1,"changeState":0}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, matt. This was exactly what I was looking for.